# Navbar dropdown not working on my local server

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've new to bootstrap and tried to do some mock layout on my local server. Things were going well until I couldn't get the navbar to work on my mock page. I've checked on bothe safari and chrome and the results are still the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
 <body>
  <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role= "navigation">
    <div class= "container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle= "collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class=" sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>

      </button>
      <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Practice</a>
    </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class= "active"> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li > <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li > <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
          <li > <a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class=  "dropdown">
              <a href="#" class= "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=" dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class= "dropdown-header">Dashboard</li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What isn't working, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popped your code into Bootply and the only thing I could see that wasn't working was your dropdown wasn't dropping down when clicked.

Your problem is on this line:

```
<a href="#" class= "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=" dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

See the extra space you have in the `data-toggle` attribute? Remove that, and your dropdown works just fine.

You also had an extra `</li>` tag in your dropdown. Doesn't break things, but it's not needed.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/WdDTBRPSXh#)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class=" sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>

      </button>
      <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Practice</a>
    </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dashboard</li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're awesome. I must admit that I haven't been paying attention to the spaces I put in my classes. Do you know why it causes the dropdown not to work? And is there a faster way to get around checking for spaces throughout ones code?

Comment: Not entirely sure as to why it breaks with the space, likely due to some way the browser is trying to read it, or possibly Bootstrap as it appears to be a custom attribute for bootstrap, thus the space throws it off. As for going through and finding these types of mistakes, I'm not aware of any "quick" methods other than knowing which part is broken, and simply analyzing the code that renders that part. Once I saw the dropdown was busted, I focused entirely on the code for just the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error into the
`<a href="#" class= "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=" dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>`

the solution is:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Themes<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Here the example:

[Fixed example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/tsgntv2m/)

```
<div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role= "navigation">
    <div class= "container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle= "collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class=" sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>

      </button>
      <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Practice</a>
    </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class= "active"> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>

            <li class=  "dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Themes<span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class= "dropdown-header">Dashboard</li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 3</a></li>           
              </ul>
            </li>                
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- navbar -->
```